# Get Tfs notifications/alerts in c#

Tags: c#, email, events, tfs, push-notification

I am trying to create a "wierd push notification". 
Every time there is a new task/request in TFS, I will get a notification in my C# program, so I can take the necessary actions...
The problem is, that as I see TFS2015 only supports sending notifications and alerts to e-mail addresses...

If there would be a solution what can notify (eg. with events) my code, that I have recieved a new e-mail... (we are using Outlook)

Anyway, if anyone have a better solution do not hold it back!

Comment: Are you using TFSVC or git? If you're using git, you might be able to accomplish what you're looking for with hook that would execute a CURL request to notify your program.

Comment: It's not git unfortunately.

Comment: TFS 2015 has Web Hooks and server-side plugins, why you cannot use those?

Comment: I can't use server side plugins because I dont have access to do it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you can develop a VSTO Add-In for Outlook to listen to the Outlook. Then you write code directly against the ThisAddIn class in your project.

Get start of the VSTO Add-In for Outlook, you can refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Server Side plugin to track the server event and send notification: [TFS Event Handler for Team Foundation Server](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/algrapsblog/archive/2014/03/18/tfs-event-handler-for-team-foundation-server).

Comment: @Farkangyal Then another solution is that create a web hooks(https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/services/webhooks) in TFS to subscription a workitem event and create a service app to review these web hooks.